# Photoshop script - Transform a rectangular selection into an oval one

Tags: javascript, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

I have a problem that I can't solve.
I have a rectangular selection (the size doesn't matter) I need to transform to elliptical with a script.
I would like the elliptical selection to have the same size and position as the rectangular one.
I managed to put this script together:

```
    (NAR = new ActionReference).putProperty (stringIDToTypeID ("channel"), stringIDToTypeID ("selection"));
    (NAD = new ActionDescriptor).putReference (stringIDToTypeID ("null"), NAR);
    (NAD2 = new ActionDescriptor).putUnitDouble (stringIDToTypeID ("top"), stringIDToTypeID ("distanceUnit"), app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[1]);
    NAD2.putUnitDouble (stringIDToTypeID ("left"), stringIDToTypeID ("distanceUnit"), app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[0]);
    NAD2.putUnitDouble (stringIDToTypeID ("bottom"), stringIDToTypeID ("distanceUnit"), app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[3]);
    NAD2.putUnitDouble (stringIDToTypeID ("right"), stringIDToTypeID ("distanceUnit"), app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[2]);
    NAD.putObject (stringIDToTypeID ("to"), stringIDToTypeID ("ellipse"), NAD2);
    NAD.putBoolean (stringIDToTypeID ("antiAlias"), true);
    executeAction (stringIDToTypeID ("set"), NAD, DialogModes.NO);
```

The script creates an elliptical selection with the same bounds as the existing rectangular selection.
The problem is that the final measure is too small and moved elsewhere outside the document's edges.
I've already tried converting the document at 72 DPI without resampling, but it still doesn't give me the correct size.
I am attaching an image for clarity.

[image]

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is overly long and ugly, but it'll change your selection to a ellipse:

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // OFF


var sb = selection_bounds(); // LRBT

selectThis(sb[0], sb[1], sb[2], sb[3], "oval");


// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL


// function SELECT THIS(top, left, right, bottom, ellipse or rect [default], antialias [default] )
// --------------------------------------------------------
function selectThis(top, left, right, bottom, shape, aa)
{
    // =======================================================
    var id1 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
    var desc1 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id2 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    var id3 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
    var id4 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
    ref1.putProperty( id3, id4 );
    desc1.putReference( id2, ref1 );
    var id5 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
    var desc2 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var id6 = charIDToTypeID( "Top " );
    var id7 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id6, id7, top );
    var id8 = charIDToTypeID( "Left" );
    var id9 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id8, id9, left );
    var id10 = charIDToTypeID( "Btom" );
    var id11 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id10, id11, bottom );
    var id12 = charIDToTypeID( "Rght" );
    var id13 = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc2.putUnitDouble( id12, id13, right );


    if (shape == "Elps" || shape == "oval")
    {
        var id14 = charIDToTypeID( "Elps" );
        desc1.putObject( id5, id14, desc2 );
        var id15 = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" );
        if (aa == true || aa == undefined)
        {
            desc1.putBoolean( id15, true );
        }
        else
        {
            desc1.putBoolean( id15, false );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var id16 = charIDToTypeID( "Rctn" );
        desc1.putObject( id5, id16, desc2 );
    }

    executeAction( id1, desc1, DialogModes.NO );

}




function selection_bounds()
{
  try
  {
    var x = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[0]);
    var y = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[1]);
    var x1 = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[2]);
    var y1 = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[3]);

    // var selectionBounds = [x, x1, y, y1]; // LRBT
    var selectionBounds = [y, x, x1, y1];    // TLBR

    return selectionBounds;

  }

  catch(eek)
  {
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

I tried unpicking your code but to no avail. I did however, note the charIDToTypeID were not four letters. ie "top should be "Top ", "bottom should be "Btom" but Adobe may have changed that.

Comment: I't's not that ugly and theoretically it works, the problem is it has the same effect as my code: the selection is too small and is placed at the top left of the document. I noticed that at 72 DPI it is slightly larger, at 300 DPI it is smaller.

Comment: As for the part in Action Manager, it's the same as yours, but I avoided using too many variables (I didn't use any) and I used StringIDs (more understandable and not limited by four letter) instead of CharIDs (they have the same result since they refer to the same TypeID). For example your selectThis function can be written like [this](https://justpaste.it/5fppt)

Comment: Hmmmm. My code selects the same size rectangle/oval at 72 or 300 dpi

Comment: I tried with Photoshop I have at home and your code works, while it doesn't work with Photoshop I have at work, so there probably must be some wrong setting. Thanks to your code I understood that I had to replace "distanceUnit" with "pixelsUnit" to my code to work (I probably copied the wrong part from an old code I had). I'll try to figure out why the codes don't work with photoshop I have at work. Thank you.

Comment: Check your units! `var originalUnits = app.preferences.rulerUnits;
alert(originalUnits);
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;
// set the units back to normal
app.preferences.rulerUnits = originalUnits;`

Comment: Yes, in the end it was the rulers that gave me problems. I don't know why, but I had checked all of them except the pixel ones. Problem solved, thank you.

Comment: Some people get into the habit of writing `#target photoshop` Switching any dialogs off `displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;` and setting the units `app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS;` at the top of every script :)